# My heroku app's generated files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

I have a rails app that is deployed to Heroku, I don't know why, but I can't view the application on localhost nor can I access the files created by `heroku run rails generate []`. The gem in this situation is activeadmin but I would like to know how to get the files that are generated from this command.

The error I get when running `rails generate active_admin:install`

```
/Users/michaelscaria/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord- 3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `initialize': FATAL:  database "crowdery_development" does not exist (PG::Error)
```

Comment: You're trying to use a generator on Heroku? Heroku doesn't exactly have a normal [writeable filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) so you shouldn't expect that to work.

Comment: @muistooshort I'm using `heroku run rails generate active_admin:install`

Comment: But don't you normally do all that stuff *before* pushing anything to Heroku?

Comment: @muistooshort Well whenever I do that before it gives me a PG::Error

Comment: You should include that information and the full error message in your question.

Comment: @muistooshort I just did!

Comment: So you haven't created your database or set up PostgreSQL then?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24487/discussion-between-michaelscaria-and-mu-is-too-short)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add gem 'pg' in your gemfile.

```
group :production do
  gem "pg"
end
```

Before bundle install you need to install 'postgresql' using command

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

After that do

```
bundle install --without production
```

Comment: if you find this answer useful please accept the answer by clicking on 'Tick'

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I didn't use the same database name that I was had created the app with.